# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions APNS when app is close

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to connect notifications when the app is closed. I need to get a message from APNS and open the desired article by id. The problem is that the message is not read by APNS inside the function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I do not know where the mistake. I'm trying to parse (NSDictionary *) launchOptions and pull out the id of the article. Inside the function - didReceiveRemoteNotification everything works fine.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[self settingMenuNotification];
[self restKitConfiguration];

[self registerSettingsAndCategories];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSLog(@"%@",[paths objectAtIndex:0]);

if(launchOptions != NULL) {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    [self openNewsDetailNotification:apsInfo];
}

return YES;
}

-(void) openNewsDetailNotification:(NSDictionary*)apsInfo {
if( [apsInfo objectForKey:@"id"] != NULL) { //id - id_article
    NSString *id_article = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"id"];

    NSNumber  *objectId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [id_article integerValue]];
    NSLog(@"Получил id %@", id_article);

    // Загружаем статью
    UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *root = [window rootViewController];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = root.storyboard;
    NewsDetailViewController *newsVC = (NewsDetailViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsDetailViewController"];

    newsVC.objectId = objectId;

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:newsVC animated:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: You only get APN data from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` if the app is not running when the user opens the notification.

Comment: @Avi if my app in background or inactive then I open notification inside didReceiveRemoteNotification

Comment: What exactly is your question or problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same happened with me.I had added delay in that.Use this code instead of directly calling the function.

```
            [self performSelector:@selector(openNewsDetailNotification:) withObject:apsInfo afterDelay:6.0f];
```

Comment: If that line "solved" anything, you have a race condition you didn't bother to diagnose and fix.

Comment: editorial comment: I hope I never use your software, if you consider this to be a solution.